# Remove unknown files in Bazaar

Tags: bazaar

I have a bunch of unknown files in my Bazaar working tree that I no longer want.  I can get a list of them using `bzr stat`, but I'd like an easy way to get rid of them.  (I'd expect an option for `bzr revert` to do this, but I'm not finding one.)

I can always write a tiny script to parse the output of `bzr stat` and `rm` or `mv` the unknowns, but I thought something might already exist.

I have Bazaar (`bzr`) 1.13.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`bzr clean-tree` will get rid of all unknown files in a working tree.  It also has switches to remove ignored files, merges backups and other types of unwanted files.  See `bzr clean-tree --usage` for full details.

Edit to add: This is true for Bazaar 2.0.0, I'm not sure about 1.13

Comment: clean-tree command coming from bzrtools plugin and available in 1.13 too.

Answer (score 0):

Made a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Move unknown files in a Bazaar repository to the trash.
# 
# Author: Benjamin Oakes

require 'fileutils'

TRASH_DIRECTORY = File.expand_path('~/.Trash/')

stdout = %x(bzr stat)

within = false

stdout.each_line do |line|
  if line.match(/^unknown:$/)
    within = true 
    next
  elsif line.match(/^[a-z]+:$/i)
    within = false
    next
  end

  if within
    FileUtils.move(line.match(/^\s+(.*?)$/)[1], TRASH_DIRECTORY)
  end
end
```

I've only tested it a little, but it seems to work just fine.  Please let me know if you find an issue via the comments.

On a separate topic, should I learn `sed` & `awk`?  I tend to write these things using `ruby -e "some ruby code"`.